# Get notified of user change in Facebook app/or mobile safari

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am using Facebook SDK 3.5.1 in my app, my requirement is that i have logged in the app via facebook with one user (say user A) and now if i login with other user (say user B) in mobile safari/facebook app (which one is available), in this case can my app get notified that another user logged in other than one who is logged in app.

Any references or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the user logged in still A, when the facebook sdk perform a login a token is obtained and stored localy in your application data, untill this token still valid the user A still logged in, when the token expire there are 2 option, the fb library renew the token silently and user A still logged in or the library need to autenticate again the user, at this point it's possible that a login dialog is presented by the fb library or the session expire and so a logout, and after a new login process the logged in user will be B. In case of iOS6 with a facebook account is pretty much the same a part for the renew process, so could be possible to fail the renew earlier because the user is changed... at the no, the library doesn't notify you that the user is changed, the app will be just logged out when the fb session expire

Comment: Thanks for this useful information Manu. I am facing problem that my app used to fetch friends of logged in user, but in this case my app logins with user A and fetching friends of user B .. :(

Comment: this could happen if the library is able to renew the token silently, for example the user has already accepted the fb app permission and can renew the token without ask again for permission. In general when a fb sessio is closed you should logout the user, so it's clear that will ne logged-in user B. The scenario that your are describing is more common for app using iOS6 fb login not safari/FB app